# Quitar margen en css

Tags: css, html5

[image: pagina hecha con html y css]

HTML

```
<header class="showcase">
      <h2 class="title">X-TOUR</h2>
      <p class="parrafo">Ushuaia - Tierra del Fuego Antártida e Islas del Atrlántico Sur</p>
            <div class="slider">
                <ul>
                   <li>
                       <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
                   </li>
                    <li>
                       <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="">
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="">
                  </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
   </header>


<div class="news-cards">
   <div>
    <img src="img/parqueNacional.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>Parque Nacional</h3>
    <p>El Parque Nacional Tierra del Fuego, fue creado mediante la Ley 15554, promulgada el 30 de septiembre de 1960. Se ubica en la esquina suroeste de la isla de Tierra del Fuego, sobre el Canal Beagle y cercano a la ciudad de Ushuaia, conservando unas 70.000 hectáreas de la Selva Patagónica que invitan a disfrutar de paseos en contacto con la naturaleza virgen. Los habitantes primitivos de esta zona fueron los aborígenes Yámanas, grupos de canoeros y mariscadores, que vivían en chozas en la zona de la Bahía de Lapataia. Hoy existen "concheros", círculos de acumulaciones de moluscos, que marcan los lugares de los antiguos asentamientos. https://ventaweb.apn.gob.ar/reserva/inicio?dp=09
    </p>
    <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/lagos.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>Lagos y más</h3>
    <p>Durante su estadía en Ushuaia, disfrute de una visita a lugares como: Laguna Esmeralda,    Lago Escondido, Laguna Turquesa, Lago Fagnano, Cerro Castor, Tolhuin, y muchos más lugares.</p>
    <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/ushuaia.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3>City Tour</h3>
    <p>Aprovecha al máximo tu visita a la ciudad más austral del mundo, terminando el día con un City Tour, para llevarte un recuerdo que no olvides nunca jamás.</p>
    <a href="#">Leer Más <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.showcase{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
color: #fff;
}
.showcase .slider{
overflow: hidden;
}

.showcase .slider ul{
display: flex;
padding: 0;
width: 400%;
animation: change 20s infinite alternate linear;
}

.showcase .slider li{
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
}

.showcase .slider img{
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
}
```

cuando achico la imagen en .showcase .slider img, a un 70% no puedo quitar ese margen que aparece en la imagen adjunta, no se que podría hacer, alguna ayuda? lo que quiero es que no se muestre ese espaciado gigante, probé con todos los margin, padding y nada..
Seguramente alguna propiedad estaré aplicando mal o me equivoque en algo, pero no logro encontrar el error. O habré puesto mal los width y height, ayuda por favooor.
Debe ser un error muy tonto quizás, pero no lo encuentro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si das height: 70%; a una imagen, esta se ajustará a un 70% respecto al 100% de su contenedor padre "slide" por lo tanto dejará el 30% disponible. Por otro lado, no es conveniente dar un height a una imagen que esta con width: 100%; ya que se deformaría, lo recomendable es que des un alto específico a su contenedor padre, y un hoverflow: hidden; para que todo lo que supere ese alto quede escondido.

Ejemplo:

```
.showcase .slider {
  max-height: 70vh; /* alto deseado del slider con respecto al alto total del viewport */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.showcase .slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* por si acaso */
}
```